# Create a chart with 4 boxplots comparing LungCapacity and the defined height groups in R

Tags: r

This is my partial example. `boxplot(____,main="Lung Capacity vs. Height",ylab="Lung Capacity",las=3,col=c(5,2,3,4))`
When I use `LungCap~Height` it gives me a scatterplot. How do I define the height groups.The four height groups are `59.9,65.4,70.3,81.8`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question gives no data, but I think I know your situation. The following toy example is relevant.

```
## toy data
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200), y = rnorm(200, sd = 3))
```

Both columns are "numeric" at the moment:

```
sapply(dat, class)
#      x         y 
#"numeric" "numeric"
```

If we make `boxplot` using:

```
boxplot(y ~ x, dat)
```

we will get a scatter plot.

[image]

`boxplot` is used for grouped data. At the moment all `x` values are unique, so there is only one `y` value per `x` value. No wonder we end up with a scatter plot.

Based on what you describe, I think we need to use `cut` to first group our data. Using `cut` is appropriate:

```
dat$x1 <- cut(dat$x, breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 0, 1, Inf))
```

Now our data looks like:

```
#           x         y        x1
#1  1.2629543 -3.137153  (1, Inf]
#2 -0.3262334 -2.688634    (-1,0]
#3  1.3297993  3.808161  (1, Inf]
#4  1.2724293  1.781523  (1, Inf]
#5  0.4146414  2.326903     (0,1]
```

Note the `x1` column is a factor / categorical variable. We could then do:

```
boxplot(y ~ x1, dat)
```

[image]

**What you can do**

```
HeightGroup <- cut(Height, breaks=c(min(Height)-1, 59.9,65.4,70.3,81.8, max(Height)+1)
```

Your break points should cover the range (min and max) of your data.

Comment: Height<-cut(Height,breaks=c(59.9,65.4,70.3,81.8). Is this what that should look like?

Answer (score 1):

boxplot(LungCap~HeightGroups,main="Lung Capacity vs. Height",ylab="Lung Capacity",las=3,col=c(5,2,3,4)) This does What I was looking for.